# Email Template Error with spanish characters

Tags: email, email-templates, email-translation

I am sending a custom email, the custom template data is in Spanish.
if the template is in the English language it's working perfectly.
but in Spanish language, it shows me unknown error.
it's not working if characters are like: ú, ó

Its not working with below code:

```
{{trans "%body" body="Transacción"|raw}}
```

Error:

> Unable to send mail: Unknown error

Comment: Is strange, we use the same format for an accented string: 
{{trans "Política de Privacidad"|raw}}

Is your store locale set to spanish?

Comment: @SantiBM Yes my store is in Spanish, other Magento email is working with spanish language.

Answer (score 0):

We can use HTML Codes for Spanish Language Characters `&uacute;` to make it take `ú` in email template,

Make sure the type is html `type="html"` in `YourVendor/YourModule/etc/email_templates.xml`

### Here are the different Spanish characters you may want to use:

```
Display FriendlyCode    NumericalCode   Hex Codes       Description

Á       &Aacute;        &#193;          &#xC1;          Capital A-acute
á       &aacute;        &#225;          &#xE1;          Lowercase a-acute
É       &Eacute;        &#201;          &#xC9;          Capital E-acute
é       &eacute;        &#233;          &#xE9;          Lowercase e-acute
Í       &Iacute;        &#205;          &#xCD;          Capital I-acute
í       &iacute;        &#237;          &#xED;          Lowercase i-acute
Ñ       &Ntilde;        &#209;          &#xD1;          Capital N-tilde
ñ       &ntilde;        &#241;          &#xF1;          Lowercase n-tilde
Ó       &Oacute;        &#211;          &#xD3;          Capital O-acute
ó       &oacute;        &#243;          &#xF3;          Lowercase o-acute
Ú       &Uacute;        &#218;          &#xDA;          Capital U-acute
ú       &uacute;        &#250;          &#xFA;          Lowercase u-acute
Ü       &Uuml;          &#220;          &#xDC;          Capital U-umlaut
ü       &uuml;          &#252;          &#xFC;          Lowercase u-umlaut
«       &laquo;         &#171;          &#xAB;          Left angle quotes
»       &raquo;         &#187;          &#xBB;          Right angle quotes
¿       &iquest;        &#191;          &#xBF;          Inverted question mark
¡       &iexcl;         &#161;          &#xA1;          Inverted exclamation point
€       &euro;          &#128;          &#x80;          Euro
₧                       &#8359;         &#x20A7;        Peseta
```

**If still not working you can create plugin:**

Define plugin: 
`YourVendor/YourModule/etc/frontend/di.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Email\Model\Template">
        <plugin name="mail_subject" type="YourVendor\YourModule\Plugin\Template" sortOrder="100" />
    </type>
</config>
```

Create Plugin:

```
<?php 
namespace YourVendor\YourModule\Plugin;

class Template
{
    public function afterProcessTemplate(
        \Magento\Email\Model\Template $subject,
        $result
    ) {
        return htmlspecialchars_decode($result, ENT_QUOTES);
    }
}
```